# how to uncompress a compressed file using system call in C

Tags: c, system-calls, unzip

I want to uncompress a tar.gz file into a unique directory using system call in C. Can anyone please help me with that. I will be running the .c file in linux.

Comment: There are no system calls in Linux to decompress files.

Comment: POSIX's `int status = system ("tar xf xfiles.tar.gz");`?

Comment: @SparKot Except that it is not a system call. It is rather a call to `system()` :P

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am not talking about system calls in Linux. I am asking about C language system calls. Is there a way to decompress a .gz file into a directory using system calls in C language. Or is there any way to do the same without a system call in C?

Comment: @SparKot- can you please show me any code for implementing the same?

Comment: A ["system call"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) is a well-defined term, and it is a call to an kernel provided service. There are no C system calls. There is a `system()` function that might be used to invoke a shell command as @SparKot shows, and it by no means a "system call".

Comment: That's it, prepare command & invoke `system()`. But you may want to look into [libArchive](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive) for C API.

Answer (score 0):

Being specific, there is no syscall for decompression.

But you can achieve this my attaching a kernel module with decompression algorithm and calling it from user space program.

Comment: Which might be an interesting but absolutely useless exercise :)

Comment: Is there any way to decompress a .gz file into a directory in C or C++ if not using system calls.